# keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*) is not going to QGraphicsItem & going into infinite loop in scene itself

Tags: qt, qt4

i have to catch keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* f_event) on item (derived from QGraphicsObject), i am not able to get the event in item, instead it is going into infinite loop in scene itself.
below is the code, thanks in advance.

```
//scene
void MyScene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* f_event)
{
   if(item && item->isSelected())
   {
     switch (f_event->key())
     {
        case Qt::Key_Up:
        case Qt::Key_Down:
        case Qt::Key_Left:
        case Qt::Key_Right:
        Item->setFocus(); //i have set item is focusable flag in item constructor.
        QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent(f_event); //here its going back to the MyScene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* f_event)again & into infinite loop, Item::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* f_event) is not calling at all
       break;
       default:
       QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent(f_event);
    }
}

//item

class Item : public QGraphicsObject
{

   Q_OBJECT
   /////////////////......///////

   protected:
   Q_DISABLE_COPY(Item);

   void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * f_event);
   void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * f_event);
   void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * f_event);
   void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* f_event);
   void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent * f_event);
};

void Item::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* f_event)
{

   QGraphicsObject::keyPressEvent(f_event);
   //qDebug()<<"keyPressEvent";
    f_event->accept();
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you solved this already?